# "ReferenceError: request is not defined" in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Firebase Cloud function  log shows the "ReferenceError: request is not defined" error when the cloud function triggered.
Here is My cloud function log output:

```
    ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at Promise.all.then.result (/srv/index.js:21:24)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Here is my index.js code:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();

    exports.requestNotification=functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}/Book_requests/{requestId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) =>{
        const object=snap.val();
        const recevierId=context.params.userId;
        const requestId=context.params.requestId;
        const requesterId=object['requesterId'];
        const bookId=object['bookId'];

        const requesterRef=admin.database().ref('/Users/'+requesterId).once('value');
        const bookRef=admin.database().ref('/Books/'+bookId).once('value');
        const recieverRef=admin.database().ref('/Users/'+recevierId).once('value');

        return Promise.all([requesterRef,recieverRef,bookRef]).then((result=>{
            const requesterName=result[0].val()['name'];
            const reciverToken=result[1].val()['deviceToken'];
            const bookTitle=result[2].val()['title'];
            const recieverName=request[1].val()['name'];
            const requesterHistory='you have requested to '+recieverName+'for the book '+bookTitle;
            const recieverHistory=requesterName+'requests for the books named '+bookTitle;
            const historyRefRequester=admin.database().ref('/Users/'+requesterId+'/History/').push({
                historyType:"request",
                historyMsg:requesterHistory
            });
            const historyRefReciever=admin.database().ref('/Users/'+recevierId+'/History/').push({
                historyType:"request",
                historyMsg:recieverHistory
            });
            return Promise.all(historyRefRequester,historyRefReciever).then((result=>{
                const payload={
                    notification:{
                        title:" Book Request ",
                        body:requesterName+" wants one of your book named "+bookTitle
                    }
                }
                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(payload,reciverToken).catch((error=>{
                    console.log('error occured',error);
                }));

            }))



        }))


    });
```

I have tried but couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You define 'recieverName' using a variable 'request', but you don't actually seem to define 'request' anywhere

Comment: As @jpthesolver2 mentioned, `request` is not declared. You probably made a typo: it seems it should be `const recieverName=result[1].val()['name'];` instead of `const recieverName=request[1].val()['name'];`. Note that the log indicates at which line in the `index.js` file you get the error: `at Promise.all.then.result (/srv/index.js:21:24)`.